# Alterar o nome de uma tabela no H2 Database Engine

Tags: sql, h2database

Estou tentando alterar o nome de uma tabela no H2, mas não encontro a sintaxe.

Alguém sabe?

Answer (score 1):

Descobri a sintaxe:

Exemplo:

```
 ALTER TABLE TEST RENAME TO MY_DATA
```

Referência: Manual da gramática do H2 Database Engine:
Disponível em : http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#alter_table_rename_constraint

Comment: Se tiver a referência à documentação oficial eu creio que atrairá mais positivos